# Styling a particuar word in android textview

Tags: android, html, textview

I have been working on an app that displays news and i want to style some particular words. I have tried
`tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Bold Text"));` 
But it doesn't satisfy my need because i wont be the one writing the news and i assume the writer have no knowledge of programming so the text should be written like %EXAMPLE% for a bold text bold.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>" +  "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + description + "</small>" + "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + DateAdded + "</small>"));
```

if you are not the one writing the news so ask for the title, description and usch and then use this code.

Comment: i understand what you mean but can i make my custom tag and have it change a text font or add smileys to my text view?

Answer (score 0):

When using `Html.fromHtml()`, you can just type text using HTML formatting, and that method will parse out the HTML tags and apply the styling for you. So if the writer wants to make a word bold, they would just surround that text with `<b>` and `</b>` tags and it will automatically be made bold in your code. You would just apply the code like this:

```
String lineOfText = "This is a line of text. To make words <b>bold</b>, simply use HTML <b>bold tags</b>.";
TextView styledText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.styledText);
styledText.setText(Html.fromHtml(lineOfText));
```